# Explain require('connect-mongo')(session);

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been learning JS/MEAN stack pretty aggressively over the past few weeks, but I missed what we're doing with the `(session)`. Are we adding the object from `var session = require('express-session');` or what..?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet in your question?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Comment: and you can see what it does with it at https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/src/connect-mongo.js#L40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems to me this is the main thing you don't understand is this:

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
```

So let's break it down a bit.  The first part of this is `require('connect-mongo')`, which basically grabs whatever gets returned from the `connect-mongo` npm package.

In this case, it's returning a function.  You can think of it somewhat like this:

```
var connectMongo = function ( expressSession ) {
    // Extends the session object that gets passed in
}
```

[Unlike IIFE's](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) the `require()` call doesn't execute the function, instead just returning a function for you to call later.  By doing `require('connect-mongo')(session)`, you're running the method returned from the `require('connect-mongo')` with the `session` passed into it.

In this case it takes the default Express session module, and returns a session store (IE a method that stores the session data into MongoDB).  It doesn't actually set up the session secret (that the server uses to sign the browser's cookie), but just returns the session storage engine that will be used.

Let's move on to the next part.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

So there are a couple things here to be aware of.  `app.use()` is the first, which isn't apparent what that means when you start using Express.  Methods you pass into `app.use()` are what are considered [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html), basically helper methods that every request will go through.

If you look at it, we are passing an `express-session` method into the middleware, and specifying that the program [should be using the MongoStore as its storage engine.](https://github.com/expressjs/session#store)  You pass in the DB options into the `new MongoStore()` method, which gives `connect-mongo` the DB credentials to actually access the database.

That's pretty much it.  Every request going to your server will have session data associated with it, and uses MongoDB to store it.  If you want to read more about how sessions and signed cookies work, you should read [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/secure-session-cookies) on security.stackexchange, it's pretty informative.

Comment: Outstanding - thanks for your more in-depth clarification. I was difficulty the flow.

Comment: @JustinSaadein No worries, I hope you understand it better now!  One thing to note, I really wouldn't use MDN for Express resources.  It might be good for .Net documentation, but for Node/ JS documentation it really is weak.  You should check out [DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/), which allows you to search through a lot of different docs all in one place. I don't personally use it for Express documentation, but the ability to search through multiple libraries / MSDN docs really is a time saver.

Comment: You just changed my life with that site. I've watched the majority of videos RE: Node/Angular/Express on Udemy, read through a good bit of a JS docs @ MDN, and started sifting through some books at Safari Books and not a single one mentioned DevDocs. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha, glad it helped you out.  Side note, I confused MDN for MSDN, sweet.

Answer (score 1):

this is just simple chaining. the sample from https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

can be re-written as

```
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStoreFactory = require('connect-mongo');
var MongoStore = mongoStoreFactory(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

does this answer your question?

Comment: I believe what the asker is asking is what does Mongo do with the Express object.

Comment: Isn't chaining object.property.method()? My concern is why '(session)' is against require('connect-mongo')? Is it that connect-mongo needs something from session and this is the shortest way to access an object? I cannot find an MDN reference. Thanks again!

Comment: your example is property access chaining, mine - function call chaining.

Comment: Your clarification edit worked perfectly. Thanks!